# how to get id from object?

Tags: javascript

I want to read the id value from the below data using JavaScript.

```
{"message_tags": {
    "12": [
        {
            "id": "153516655618",
            "name": "Royal Challengers Bangalore",
            "length": 27,
            "offset": 57,
            "type": "page"
        }
    ],
    "97":  [
        {
            "id": "198358615428",
            "name": "Mumbai Indians",
            "length": 14,
            "offset": 98,
            "type": "page"
        }
    ]
}}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Which programming language are you using to parse this JSON? Are you using any libraries or tools to help you? Do you have any code to show us where you are keeping the JSON?

Comment: @IanGabes using javascript

Comment: That is not valid JSON. Consult http://jsonlint.com/. Message tags key has a value of type object. This object does not have any properties - you just have a bunch of arrays with no keys to assign to.

Comment: You have more than one `id` property. Which one do you want to access? I suggest you go back and bone up on basic JS data structures and how to reference object properties and array elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way you can get the data:

```
message_tags.12[0].id

message_tags.97[0].id
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: `message_tags.12` is invalid syntax. I assume you also want to prefix `message_tags` with the object name.